# Inclusion/exclusion of the field during serialization

Tags: java, json, serialization

I am having a POJO class with ,

```
class Test {
   @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
   Mgmt mgmt;

}

class Mgmt {
   @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
   List<String> values;
}
```

During serialization of Test , 'Mgmt' field is coming as mgmt : {} still written out despite ‘NON_EMPTY’ inclusion criteria used. I would like to avoid the field mgmt : {}, if Mgmt class -> values has empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because the default implementation of `JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY` understands "emptiness" just for standard data types (a collection, a string...) but not for a custom data type like `Mgmt`.

Since that's your class, it's only you knowing what "empty" (or not) means and in your specific case, emptiness is given by the fact that one of its properties (`List<String> values`) is itself empty.

To achieve that, you can define a custom filter for `Mgmt` emptiness (it's a simple class where you override the `equals` method to make it return `true` everytime you want to filter that instance out of the serialized Json:

```
class MgmtFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Mgmt)) {
            return true; //<-- not an instance of Mgmt so we filter it out
        }
        return ((Mgmt) obj).values.isEmpty(); //<-- if the list is empty, we return true (meaning we filter it out)
    }
}
```

... and then you use this class with a custom include:

```
class Test {
    @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = MgmtFilter.class)
    Mgmt mgmt;
}
```

Comment: P.s. of course you will have to check that "values" is not null and eventually see if you need a public getter to access the value, but I let you handle the details